# Is there a derived version of affine Schur-Weyl duality?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, derived-categories, geometric-representation-theory, kac-moody-algebras, affine-hecke-algebras

One version of affine Schur-Weyl duality states that there is a fully faithful functor from representation of $A_r$ affine Hecke algebra to the representation of $A_n$ affine Lie group assuming $r<n$. Can we extend this to an embedding of corresponding derived category?

(This is equivalent to ask if extension groups of Schur algebra representation are the same as their extension groups viewed as affine Lie group representation.)

One can also ask a quantum version of this question.